# jQuery $.each or $.map to append <tr> to dynamically added tables

Tags: jquery, html, foreach, html-table

I am using an a jQuery AJAX response to dynamically build a bootstrap table within a panel.

I can get it to create the panel and add a table to the panel but I've got a problem looping through the AJAX response to create the table rows and cells.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    success: function(response) {
        $('#groups').append(
            $('<div/>', {'class': 'panel panel-default'}).append(
                $('<div/>', {'class': 'panel-heading'}).append(
                    $('<span/>', {text: 'TEST'})
                )
            ).append(
                $('<div/>', {'class': 'panel-body'}).append(
                    $('<div/>', {class: 'table-responsive'}).append(
                        $('<table/>', {class: 'table table-bordered'}).append(

                        )
                    )   
                )
            )
        );
    }
});
```

The expected output is:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
         TEST
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but at the moment I get this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
         TEST
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I loop through the response to create a `<tr>` for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('#groups').append(
            $('<div/>', {'class': 'panel panel-default'}).append(
                $('<div/>', {'class': 'panel-heading'}).append(
                    $('<span/>', {text: $('#productgroup option:selected').text() + '/' + $('#productline option:selected').text() + '/' + $('#producttype option:selected').text()})
                )
            ).append(
                $('<div/>', {'class': 'panel-body'}).append(
                    $('<div/>', {class: 'table-responsive'}).append(
                        $('<table/>', {class: 'table table-bordered table-striped'}).append(
                            $.map(response, function (k, v) {
                                return $('<tr/>').append(
                                    $('<td>', {text: 'some text'})
                                ).append(
                                    $('<td>', {text: 'some more text'})
                                );
                            })
                        )
                    )   
                )
            )
        );
```